# React PrivateRoute not returning boolean, but promise

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm creating a privateRoute file that checks for the user token in the server side and checks if it is still valid.
the fetch function should return true or false depending if it is valid or not, and when this value is checked, decide whether if it goes to the outlet or ot the accessrestricted page.

```
const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
 
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
      const res = await Rolcheck(tokenString);
      return res;
  }
  const auth = handleSubmit();

  return (auth ? <Outlet/> : <Restricted/>)

}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Note that Rolcheck (named after what I will do in the future with it) is an async function that sends the token to the db and compares it there, then returns true or false depending on this.

After a console.log(), I can get the right expected boolean option if I check inside `handleSubmit`, however, the `const auth` gets a promise. I'm not sure If this is messed due to async/await.

Comment: maybe you can add await on auth, so become like this const auth = await handleSubmit();

Comment: @wisnu it throws: Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (15:15)

Comment: if i make the const PrivateRoutes = async() then I get the following error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Comment: Just remove async from handleSubmit 
and it will not return promise it will return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const [state,setState] = useState(undefined)

  useEffect(()=>{
     Rolcheck(tokenString).then(setState).catch(()=>setState(false))
  },[])
 
 if(state === undefined)
   return <React.Fragment/>

  return (auth ? <Outlet/> : <Restricted/>)
}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Comment: it worked, but I had to change from your reply "auth" to "state". This way it seems to work. Is my correction what you intented?

Comment: You can use different name. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just replied here to write a more complete code. Have you try with this:

```
const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');

const PrivateRoutes = () => {

  const handleSubmit = async () => await Rolcheck(tokenString);

  const auth = await handleSubmit();

  return (auth ? <Outlet/> : <Restricted/>)

}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Comment: can't use await here: "const auth = await handleSubmit();" Throws the same error that I stated above. If I just dont type it, auth is an [object promise], not the proper return.